# ng-if causing $parent.$index to be set to $index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeater with a nested ng-repeater contained within it. In the nested repeater I am trying to track the parents $index value, this works fine. However, when I introduce an ng-if in the same element that has a reference to $parent.$index, the parents index is set to the child's index. Any ideas on this? The code is running [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mtCuPD?p=preview). An example would be, I click on index 1 of parent 0 and get index 1 parent 1 as indexes.

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.arr = [["a","b","c"],["d","f","e"],["f","h","i"]];

  $scope.logIndex = function(index, parent) {
    console.log("index: " + index + ", parent: " + parent);
  };

});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="i in arr">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="j in i">
         <span ng-click="logIndex($index, $parent.$index)" ng-if="$index > 0">{{ j }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `ng-if` creates a child scope on the element, so `$parent` is actually its immediate ng-repeat's child scope, not the parent one, and the $index is again the same $index inherited from its immediate parent (i.e second ng-repeat's childscope). You can use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to alias special properties of ng-repeat and use that property instead of using $parent.

```
   <li ng-repeat="i in arr" ng-init="parentIndex=$index">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="j in i">
         <span ng-click="logIndex($index, parentIndex)" ng-if="$index > 0">{{ j }} </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/caganebuna/1/edit)**